# Good Open Source Software to Analyse

Tags: java, c++, c, open-source

I'm looking for an informative and important **open source software product to do an investigation and analysis** for my University project. What are some good open source projects to study on? I prefer something written in Java, C, C++ etc.

This study is a comparison between programming languages (**language evaluation**) like if the product was developed in Java, why it wasn't developed in other language like C **considering algorithm complexity, loc, simplicity, reliability etc.**

Any recommendations?

Comment: This is too vague to answer. You'll have to have *some* area or technology that you're interested in to narrow down. What is your investigation and analysis about?

Comment: What kind of analysis and what are you studying? You can analyse a lot, from lines of code to algorithm complexity. Some oss implementation of the STL or Boost may be interesting. You could analyse the whole thing or a single class, depending on your needs.

Comment: No it would be better if it is windows based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hit one of the open source hosting services like [Github](https://github.com/), [Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/), SourceForge, Launchpad, etc.  Cruise through the repositories in there until you find something interesting.  There are literally thousands of projects in there--git, jQuery, rails (Ruby on Rails), django, V8, Greasemonkey, etc.  You can blow hours just sifting through all the stuff available.  It depends what interests you and what you want to study.  The more popular projects will probably have more information on why a certain language was chosen (ie, for speed, developer familiarity, interop with existing tools, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a good selection of java open source projects try http://java-sources.net/ This shows you in a small number of pages a short description of each project, grouped by usage.

Answer (score 0):

I would loook at JAMA http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/ a matrix package from NIST in Java. It's effectively finished. This should give you opportunities to compare their approach with other matrix libraries

Comment: I was targeting at some bigger and popular product like 'Firefox', 'Open Office' etc.